# PHP - Message encryption

Tags: php, encryption

I am designing a social application which will of course, have a messaging feature.  I want to implement an encryption scheme in which nobody(except the sender and receiver) would be able to view the deciphered message.  I don't know how(or where) to store the keys either.  Would anyone be so kind as to suggest an algorithm that I could use, and/or a key storage method?  Please keep in mind that I am using PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might take a look at the openssl functions:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php